How to customize Documents button with MacCatalyst
When I built and ran a simple Document Based Storyboard iPad app on a Mac, the following interface appeared.

Also when I enabled Mac Catalyst and the Optimize for Mac option in Interface, I see the following:

How can I control whether this 'Documents' button is shown or hidden? And what function does this button have exactly?
Please let me know if you know, it would be very helpful.
